# Switch from XM to Sirius on a 2013 Nissan Altima

Tags: nissan, audio, altima

I have a new (to me) 2013 Nissan Altima SV.  The car comes w/ XM installed, but I'd like to switch this to Sirius, since the two companies do not allow you to have both types of radios on one account (despite merging 5 years ago).

I've accomplished this in the past w/ a 2009 GMC Acadia.  I was able to buy a small part; about the size of a desktop hard-drive.  I then had a car-audio shop swap the parts, and have been using Sirius ever since on that vehicle.

Does anyone know how feasible it is to accomplish this w/ my Altima?

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this?

Answer (score 1):

I asked around, and here was one response from an car audio specialist:

> The future is the XM network, so basically the Sirius network is
>   'as-is' and only providing limited hardware.  The SCC1 tuner is
>   discontinued and it is required for the Sirius kits.
>
> It looks like the ISNI572 kit should work with your Altima, provided
>   it doesn't already have satellite radio, but also meets this criteria:
>
> 1> Radio must have a "SAT" button or have "CH", "CHANNEL", "CAT" or
>   "CATEGORY" printed somewhere on the face of the radio to be
>   compatible. This is usually located near the Tune or Seek buttons.
>
> If you already have the SCC1 module for some reason, then you would
>   just need the iSimple NI2 kit with the satellite radio cable and
>   probably an antenna of some sort (or an adapter if it has a satellite
>   radio antenna on the roof already).
>
> Vehicles that don't meet the criteria above, or have navigation, are
>   automatically excluded.  Many vehicles have the XM receiver module
>   inside the in-dash radio now, instead of as a separate box, which
>   makes many late model vehicles not capable of conversion.

Also, it looks like SiriusXM will let you combine different radio subscriptions on one account now (see [this link](http://siriusbuzz.com/finally-sirius-xm-offers-cross-platform-multi-subscription-discounts.php)); even when one radio is Sirius and the other radio is XM.  I haven't actually tried this yet, but I will soon when I can no longer tolerate FM radio (very soon).